# ReactJS not displaying the HTML in when clicked on View Page Sorce

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux

I am new to ReactJS, and I want to build a ReactJS website and futher implement SEO to it. While practicing whenever I click to "View Page Source" option, it does not the display whole html of page, instead it only displays content of `index.html`.

I tried implementing it with server-side rendering reference from [here,](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/server-side-rendering-your-react-app-in-three-simple-steps-7a82b95db82e)

but it didn't worked.

When I build and run this with- `npm run build && npm run start`, it gives error :-

```
  project_frontend@0.1.0 babel /usr/react_projects/project_frontend
> babel src -d views

 { SyntaxError: /usr/react_projects/project_frontend/src/bundle.js: Unexpected token (8:2)

   6 | const store = configureStore();
   7 | render(
>  8 |   <Provider store={store}>
     |   ^
   9 |     <App />
  10 |   </Provider>,
  11 |   document.querySelector("#app")
  at Parser.raise (/usr/react_projects/project_frontend/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:4028:15)
  at Parser.unexpected (/usr/react_projects/project_frontend/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:5343:16)
  at Parser.parseExprAtom (/usr/react_projects/project_frontend/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:6432:20)
  at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (/usr/react_projects/project_frontend/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:6019:21)
  at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (/usr/react_projects/project_frontend/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:5998:21)
  at Parser.parseExprOps (/usr/react_projects/project_frontend/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:5907:21)
  at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (/usr/react_projects/project_frontend/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:5879:21)
  at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (/usr/react_projects/project_frontend/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:5826:21)
  at Parser.parseExprListItem (/usr/react_projects/project_frontend/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:7111:18)
  at Parser.parseCallExpressionArguments (/usr/react_projects/project_frontend/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:6227:22)
pos: 234,
loc: Position { line: 8, column: 2 },
code: 'BABEL_PARSE_ERROR' }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project_frontend@0.1.0 babel: `babel src -d views`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project_frontend@0.1.0 babel script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2018-11-26T04_40_59_532Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project_frontend@0.1.0 build: `npm run pack && npm run babel`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project_frontend@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2018-11-26T04_40_59_580Z-debug.log
```

Can anyone please suggest a better way/tutorial to implement this.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. There's plenty of tutorials about how to implement SSR in React, so best to show what you tried and *specifically* how it wasn't working.

Comment: @Jayce444 please check the updated question.

Comment: Hi
did you solve this issue? thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use [react-meta-tags](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-meta-tags). It allows you to meta tags in a declarative way and in normal jsx format, which will be moved to head (Check server usage on the doc).

```
import React from 'react';
import MetaTags from 'react-meta-tags';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div class="wrapper">
          <MetaTags>
            <title>Page 1</title>
            <meta id="meta-description" name="description" content="Some description." />
            <meta id="og-title" property="og:title" content="MyApp" />
            <meta id="og-image" property="og:image" content="path/to/image.jpg" />
          </MetaTags>
          <div class="content"> Some Content </div>
        </div>
      )
  }
}
```

Or you can use JS to change meta tags inside your `componentDidMount()` method

```
document.title ="Welcome | here is your page title to display"; 
document.getElementsByTagName("META")[2].content="Your description about the page or site here to set dynamically";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to view page source,
you will see this

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script ........./>
</body>
```

when ReactJS dev server runs, the bundle.js is auto-compiled and the page will be re-rendered.

The reason why you can't see full page source is natural.
So If you want to see source work on browser, please use React/Redux Development Extension on browser

Comment: But I want to implement SEO to it, and for that I would need the full page source.

Comment: @ReemaParakh Same Question I have, Have you implemented those things in react?

Comment: No @ChetanNada. I ended up using NextJS. It is React-based web applications with server-side rendering. For SEO purpose you need server-side rendering.